# How to construct a database of HDF5 files

Tags: database, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5, h5py

I have been exploring data storage capabilities of HDF5 and found it to be useful for storing large results. I have a bunch of hdf5 files on my local machine, with different hierarchical structure. Now, my aim is to construct a database/database like structure of these files so that i can perform basic queries on it. For example let's say i need to find the dataset with name "ds", then my search results should include all the datasets from the HDF5 files with the given string name.

I will be using python 3.5 for building such a system. A little bit of online search led me to 3 available API's that are available in python for HDF5; h5py, pandas and pytables. I have used pandas before and found it to be great, so I am leaning in that direction. Also  there is this nice project http://www.hdfql.com/; but I need to dig more into this.

Another direction would be to import data to relational database so that i can perform sql, but that seems to destroy the point of storing data into hdf5 format.

So, I need help/pointers regarding this.

Comment: In `h5py`, `group.visit` provides an easy way to fetch the names of all datasets.  That could be basis for collecting the data for each file.

Comment: Since you already have HDF5 files, have you investigated external links? You could create a primary HDF5 file with links to your other files. Then when you interrogate the primary file for dataset names, you would find ALL of them. And, if you create more HDF5 data files, you can add links to them as well. Note PyTables also has functions to fetch node, group and dataset names: walk_nodes(), inter_nodes() and walk_groups() are a few of them. `h5py` is more numpy like, and `PyTables` has extensive dataset search capabilities.

Comment: @kcw78 I looked into external links, seems like a good solution to my project. I will try to implement it and see how it performs. Thank you .

Comment: @kcw78 can you provide me with a link which describes those extensive dataset search capabilities?

Comment: PyTables has online docs here: [PyTables User’s Guide](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/index.html) . Be sure to check out the "Other Material" tab. There is lots of great info about 'advanced' skills. I also have a PDF. Best I can tell, the PDF is identical (or nearly identical) to the online material. Unfortunately, I can't figure out where I got it. :-(

Comment: HDFql.com has no relation with The HDF Group.

"HDFql was launched in 2016 by a team of interdisciplinary experts with vast experience from world leading research facilities (such as CERN), Fortune 50, and top universities in the United States and Europe. "

Comment: https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov will be a good example of using Elastic Search and metadata relational database to query HDF5 collection.

Comment: @HDFEOS.org thank you for pointing this, I have edited my post

Comment: First of all thank you for pointing out this, I am now experimenting with elasticsearch, I setup the elasticsearch environment for python3 and for few entries it works properly then it throws a read timeout error, i tried increasing the read time but nothing seems to change. What could be the problem? All the entries to the elasticsearch index are TEXT.